EF Core: SQL for persisting property that references list of derived types (TPH) is performed alphabetically instead of respecting collection order
Here's one more question about EF Core and how it performs it's operations internally.
Ok, here's the scenario: I have a hierarchy of types which are mapped to a single table. The code has a couple of years and it favors a more OO approach instead of having classes which are mapped almost directly into tables (after all, this is C#, right?).
Until now, I was using NHibernate to persist the data into a SQL Server database (and Fluent NH for the mappings).Here's a snippet of the classes:
public abstract class Intervencao : Entity 
{
    private Acao _acao;

    //nh
    protected Intervencao() 
    {
        Prioridade = PrioridadePedido.Normal;
        EstadoPedido = EstadoPedido.Aberto;
        ObservacaoUtente = ObservacoesUtente.ObservacoesEstadoParaUtente.First();
        Acao = new Acao("-", DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    public Intervencao(Acao acao) : this() 
    {
        Acao = acao ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(acao));
    }

    // other properties removed. These include references to other
    // entities and value types (DDD lingo)
}

// There are several derived types, but I'll just show 1 here

public class IntervencaoEquipamentos : Intervencao {
    private IList<Equipamento> _equipamentosAssociados = new List<Equipamento>();

    protected IntervencaoEquipamentos() 
    {
    }

    public IntervencaoEquipamentos(Acao acao) : base(acao) 
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Equipamento> EquipamentosAssociados 
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Equipamento>(_equipamentosAssociados); }
        private set { _equipamentosAssociados = new List<Equipamento>(value); }
    }

    // other properties not shown

}


These classes are mapped into a single table with the following code:
public sealed class IntervencaoTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Intervencao> 
{
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Intervencao> builder) 
    {
        builder.ToTable("IntervencaoPATs");

        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        builder.Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("IdIntervencaoPATs");

        builder.Property(i => i.Version)
               .IsConcurrencyToken( )
               .HasColumnName("Versao");

       // other mappings omitted
       // but here's the discriminator
       builder.HasDiscriminator(g => g.TipoIntervencao)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoGenerica>(TipoIntervencao.Generica)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoEquipamentos>(TipoIntervencao.Equipamentos)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoTecnicos>(TipoIntervencao.Tecnicos)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoDadosGerais>(TipoIntervencao.DadosGerais)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoDocumentoAdicionado>(TipoIntervencao.DocumentoAdicionado)
               .HasValue<IntervencaoDocumentoRemovido>(TipoIntervencao.DocumentoRemovido);

        builder.Property(g => g.TipoIntervencao)
               .HasColumnName("TipoPedido");
}

// and here's IntervencaoEquipamentos mapping
public sealed class IntervencaoEquipamentosTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<IntervencaoEquipamentos> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IntervencaoEquipamentos> builder) 
    {
        builder.HasBaseType<Intervencao>( );

        builder.HasMany(g => g.EquipamentosAssociados)
               .WithMany( )
               .UsingEntity(
                   "EquipamentosAssociados",
                   r => r.HasOne(typeof( Equipamento )).WithMany( ).HasForeignKey("IdEquipamento"),
                   l => l.HasOne(typeof( IntervencaoEquipamentos )).WithMany( ).HasForeignKey("IdIntervencaoPATs"));
        builder.Navigation(g => g.EquipamentosAssociados).AutoInclude( );
    }
}


Now, the instances are always used from within the PedidoAssistencia aggregate, which looks like this:
public class PedidoAssistencia : Entity, IVersionamento 
{
     private IList<Intervencao> _intervencoes = new List<Intervencao>();
     
     // just showing the collection for intervencoes
     public IEnumerable<Intervencao> Intervencoes 
     {
        get => new ReadOnlyCollection<Intervencao>(_intervencoes);
        internal set => _intervencoes = new List<Intervencao>(value);
     }

     // remaining code omitted
}

And here is its mapping:
public sealed class PedidoAssistenciaTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<PedidoAssistencia> 
{
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PedidoAssistencia> builder) 
    {
        // just showing this property
       
        builder.HasMany(p => p.Intervencoes)
               .WithOne(i => i.PedidoAssistencia)
               .HasForeignKey("IdPATs");
        builder.Navigation(p => p.Intervencoes).AutoInclude();
}

And here's a snippet of the integration test code we have to test the mappings:
// pat is a PedidoAssistencia instance
// and we're adding several kinds of intervencao to it
PedidoAssistencia pat = new(Guid.NewGuid( )) 
    {
        VerificadorPermissoesPedidoAssistencia = new Verificador( )
    };
await pat.ModificaAsync(_intervencaoDadosGerais);
await pat.ModificaAsync(_intervencaoTecnicos);
await pat.ModificaAsync(_intervencaoGenerica);
await pat.ModificaAsync(_intervencaoEquipamentos);
await pat.AdicionaDocumentoAsync(_documento.NomeDocumento,
                    _documento.Descricao,
                    _documento.Acao,
                    _documento.Bytes.Bytes,
                    EstadoPedido.Aberto,
                    PrioridadePedido.Media,
                    ObservacoesUtente.AguardaIntervencao);

Now, when we relied on NHibernate to persist this info to the database, it respected the collection enumeration order (ie, _intervencaoDadosGerais was inserted first because it was the first object stored by the Intervencoes collection, then _intervencaoTecnicos, then intervencaoGenerica and so on).
However, we're seeing a different behavior with EF: instead of repecting the order of the Intervencoes property, it will instead generate the SQL INSERT instructions according to the alphabetical order of the types used in the TPH. Going back to the sample, this means that will start by inserting the intervencaoDadosGerais and then it will jump into the IntervencaoDocumentoAdicionado which is generated by the AdicionaDocumentoAsync call.
Here's what the collection looks like before inserting the data into the DB (captured during a debug session on Jetbrains Rider):

And here's what it looks like after recovering it from the DB:

This completely breaks the app because each Intervencao changes properties that affect the current state of the PedidoAssistencia and makes using EF Core simply impossible.
So, is this a bug? Anyone know how to make EF Core respect the collection order while saving a TPH list to the database?
Thanks.
EDIT: just to mention that I've opened an issue on Github if anyone else cares about this.

Don't think that you can control this. EF Core uses topological sorting for place operations in right order which do not break foreign keys. I don't think it cares about some collections order. Introduce field SortOrder in Intervencao

Hello. But shouldn't saving the top object (pat in the image) perform the associated saving for each ítem of the list instead of sorting them alphabetically by typename? I really can't understand the need to do that when All the items on the collection are persisted to The same table and none of them depends on the other...

Have you tried to use Enum as discriminator value, instead of type?

Hello again. The discriminator is an enum type...
